# Detecting failed fingerprint authentication attempts in an Android app

Tags: android, authentication, fingerprint

Disclaimer: First of all I'm not an Android developer but a security professional.

My company wants to implement fingerprint authentication in its Android app and I'm wondering if there is any way to log the failed authentication attempts in the application?

According to my current understanding after the application calls the fingerprint authentication API of the OS it does not see how many times the user failed to provide a valid fingerprint, it only waits for a callback containing the key extracted from the keystore in case of successful authentication or a "fingerprint authentication canceled" message if the user decides not to use the fingerprint authentication and fall back to PIN authentication instead (let's suppose that this is implemented).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/fingerprint/FingerprintManager.html) when you launch the FingerprintManager, you provide a [AuthenticationCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/fingerprint/FingerprintManager.AuthenticationCallback.html) listener.

This listener contain a method `onAuthenticationFailed()` that will be called every time a correct fingerprint has been detected and that given fingerprint is not registered in the device.
This callback is available since the API 23 in the native Android system and in the compatibility libraries
On this callback we should be able to do whatever you want.

But this may differ if you'r using any third-party library.

I hope that, this will help you.

Comment: Thanks, seems helpful :)